# NodeJS Sequelize ORM db:seed:all drops tables from db

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have models set up without migrations which create the DB. 
and I created seeders for the tables in respected Order.

When I run sequelize db:seed:all 
it fills the tables but for some reason it drops half of the tables.

Has Anyone encountered this?

Comment: I just ran each seeder on its own using db:seed --seed and all seeders worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue I was using one of the models in one of the seeders and by requiring the models folder. (which was completely idiotic of me) it was triggering the recreation of the database (since flush was true).